# Problema al actualizar el Firebase Crashlytics SDK

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, gradle, build.gradle

Estoy siguiendo los pasos para migrar de [Fabric Crashlytic a Firebase Craslytic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=android) y me esta dando el siguiente problema, me sale el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el **build.gradle** del proyecto lo tengo de la siguiente forma:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.1.1'
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.72'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        //mavenLocal() must be listed at the top to facilitate testing
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

y el **build.gradle: app** de la siguiente forma:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }

    dependencies {

        // Add the Google Services Gradle plugin (if it's not there already).
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        // Add the Firebase Crashlytics Gradle plugin.
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.1.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

// Apply the Google Services plugin (if it's not there already).
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

// Add the Firebase Crashlytics plugin.
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/fabric-artifacts-private/internal-snapshots' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    //buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "------------"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 19
        versionName "1.0.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    // Gradle automatically adds 'android.test.runner' as a dependency.
    useLibrary 'android.test.runner'

    useLibrary 'android.test.base'
    useLibrary 'android.test.mock'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient-android', version: '4.3.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.szagurskii:patternedtextwatcher:0.5.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // Add the Firebase Crashlytics SDK.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.0.1'

    // Recommended: Add the Google Analytics SDK.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.3'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

he probado a añadir `implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'` pero no consigo arreglarlo, e buscado por internet y no encuentro mucha mas información. ¿Alguna sugerencia para arreglar el problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de muchas pruebas, he resuelto el problema, en mi caso se resolvió eliminando:

```
// Add the Google Services Gradle plugin (if it's not there already).
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
// Add the Firebase Crashlytics Gradle plugin.
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.1.1'
```

del fichero build.gradle: app del apartado dependencies del buildscript, quedando el archivo de la siguiente forma:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }

    dependencies {

    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

// Apply the Google Services plugin (if it's not there already).
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

// Add the Firebase Crashlytics plugin.
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/fabric-artifacts-private/internal-snapshots' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    //buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "------------"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 19
        versionName "1.0.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    // Gradle automatically adds 'android.test.runner' as a dependency.
    useLibrary 'android.test.runner'

    useLibrary 'android.test.base'
    useLibrary 'android.test.mock'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient-android', version: '4.3.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.szagurskii:patternedtextwatcher:0.5.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // Add the Firebase Crashlytics SDK.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.0.1'

    // Recommended: Add the Google Analytics SDK.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.3'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1):

Me llama la atenciòn el error, ya que hace referencia a la clase GSON, en este caso seguramente una dependencìa o versiòn de dependencia provoca el problema.

Para implementar Firebase Crashlytics, actualmente las dependencias necesarias son, en el archivo `build.gradle` en la raìz del proyecto:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google() 
        maven {
           url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
 

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.0'  // Crashlytics plugin

        
    }
}

allprojects {
    
    repositories {
   
       google() 

    }
}
```

y dentro del `build.gradle` que se encuentra dentro del directorio `/app` se agregan las dependencias:

```
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

dependencies {
   
    //Firebase Analytics
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'

    // Crashlytics
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
}
```

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, según la página de migración ya no se deben gastar ni maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' } ni apply plugin: 'io.fabric' porque se sustituyen por los de firebase, según lo que estuve probando creo que el error me lo daba por lo que he puesto en la respuesta, que duplique los classpath en los dos archivos build.gradle cuando solo tiene que estar en el de la raíz del proyecto